# How to stop a UIScrollView at a specific point?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

How do you stop a `UIScrollView` at specific point? That is, set the final position of the `UIScrollView` after user interaction?

Specifically, how can you set intervals along a horizontal `UIScrollView`, so that the it will only stop at these points?

I hope what I have said is clear enough.

Comment: Note that the "remarkably simple" way to do this is, just make the scroll view only as wide as each "unit" - and set paging. You're done.  Note that it's fine to have the "rest of the scroll view" "hanging off the sides" of the "actual" scroll view. You have to carefully manipulate the touchable area if necessary.

Comment: @JoeBlow that solves the issue for some I'm sure, but it doesn't answer the question. I wanted to be able to set the scroll position to *any* specific point... paging isn't the answer here.

Comment: Hey Jesse - by all means.  I was just pointing out the "super simple" way to achieve this, which typically you can use!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Take a look at method `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` of `UIScrollViewDelegate`.  It's intended to do exactly what you need.

The scroll view sends this message to its delegate when the user finishes dragging the scroll view.  The third parameter (`targetContentOffset`) is passed as a pointer, and you can change its value to change where the scroll view will stop.

iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: @JesseHead So what was your final answer?

Comment: note that in many cases, you will also use `scrollViewDidScroll` - so that, the value will change as the user holds-and-moves the slider.

Comment: for other n00bs like me, you can change `targetContentOffset` by updating `targetContentOffset.pointee` to a new `CGPoint` value ;)

Answer (score 11):

You've got 3 options:

1. You can do so using [`pagingEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/pagingEnabled).
2. Use [`setContentOffset: animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset:animated:) in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` method
3. Create your own scroll view using `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` and extrapolate to create momentum with a appropriate endpoint

Comment: Finally someone is starting to understand what I'm looking for lol. number 2 is looking pretty appealing. will see how it works.

Comment: Would you know how to detect the current position of the scrollview as the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: method is triggered?

Comment: The current position is stored in the `contentOffset` (CGPoint) property

Comment: @JesseHead what did you end up using?

Answer (score 4):

I've found something that works for me. It let's you scroll to point 0,0 but no further:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x <= -1) {
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

You could do the same for top, bottom or right (x or y)

Comment: Helped me out a ton!

Answer (score 2):

to achieve this u need to enable the paging of the scrollview

For example:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640, 161)];
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

here, width of scrollview is 640 (twice of width of iphone screen), if paging is enabled it will divide it equally depending on the width. So as we scroll to this position it will stop at the particular  offset.

Comment: yeah... i looked at that originally, but i want to allow my content to stop at any number of positions after a swipe. paging only allows one set distance to be moved per swipe (in this case 320 pixels i believe?). this is hard to explain... if you have a look at the free news app called 'pulse' it shows what i am after.

Comment: actually if the content size of scrollview is more then screen size, user can set to the fixed position as scrolling horiz/vert... do u want to do this by code..?

Comment: u can do by implementing its delegate methods, & using its offset value u can have either scroll more or stop scrolling...

Comment: use - (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated to scroll by code to a fixed position (offset), calculate the exact offset required..

Comment: ahh yeah, but wouldn't a separate event have to occur for the above method to be triggered? i want it to occur automatically after the scrolling has ended.

Comment: in didscrollend delegate u can do this... go through the delegate methods list once...

Answer (score 2):

For those we need to set the `targetContentOffset` in Swift like **rob mayoff** says in his excellent answer above , this is the way :

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.memory.y = x 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work just fine:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > CERTAIN_POINT {
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640, 161)];
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help you check this API provided by apple

- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated

And apple clearly said about this **This method scrolls the content view so that the area defined by rect is just visible inside the scroll view. If the area is already visible, the method does nothing.**

Answer (score 0):

For vertical scrolling i use this . Worked perfectly

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, desiredPoint.y);
  }